# How can I merge ASP .NET Identity/ Identity Framework DbContext class to my DbContext class which is on another Assembly/ Project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller, asp.net-identity

I have implement N-tier architecture in  my MVC application (using Code-First Approach); in this I have my DB in separate assembly and MVC in separate assembly. So, I want my asp .net identity tables to be added into my existing database dbcontext class.

I have tried to merge this but it recreates my existing database with no asp .net identity tables.

Here is the Asp. net identity DbContext Class(which is in separate assembly:

```
namespace MVC_ExplorePak.Models
{

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

And below is my existing DB dbcontext class in another assembly:

```
namespace EF_DB
{
public class EFContext: DbContext
{
    public EFContext(): base("Constr")
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
        .HasMany<Color>(p => p.ColorsOffered)
        .WithMany();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
            .HasMany<Size>(p => p.SizesOffered)
            .WithMany();

        modelBuilder.Entity<PackageInfo>()
            .HasMany<TourGuide>(p => p.TourGuide)
            .WithMany();

        modelBuilder.Entity<PackageInfo>()
        .HasMany<TourDay>(p => p.TourDays)
        .WithMany();

        //Necessity of time
        modelBuilder.Entity<Hotel>()
        .HasMany<HotelRoom>(p => p.RoomsInformation)
        .WithMany();
    }

    public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Province> Provinces { get; set; }

    public DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Location> Locations { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

    public DbSet<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Size> Sizes { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Color> Colors { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Fabric> Fabrics { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Hotel> Hotels { get; set; }

    public DbSet<HotelRoom> HotelRooms { get; set; }

    public DbSet<PackageInfo> PackageInfos { get; set; }

    public DbSet<TourGuide> TourGuides { get; set; }

    public DbSet<DriverDetail> DriverDetails { get; set; }

    public DbSet<VehicleInfo> VehicleInfos { get; set; }

}
}
```

And lastly, here is my connection string in MVC assembly:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <add name="Constr" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=ExplorePakDB;user id=myid;password=mypass" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

So, how can I merge Asp .net Identity DbContext class in my DbContext class. Please once again keep in mind that they both are in different assembly under same solution.

Comment: What do you mean merge these context? It is not enough for you to give the same connection string to both context?

Comment: @cptiv I mean that can I have only one dbcontext class(in my Database assembly) which will covers the my classes/tables as well as the asp .net identity classes/tables.

Comment: If its possible to give same connection string for both dbcontext classes you can tell me how to do it, If you saw my connection string above in the question you will find out it's specifically for my existing DbContext class not for asp .net identity

Comment: Use "name=Constr" instead of "DefaultConnection" for your ApplicationDbContext and for both context set different ContextKey in DbMigrationsConfiguration.

Answer (score 0):

If by merging you mean having one DbContext for both Identity and Data what you need to do is this:

1. Move `ApplicationUser` to the DB assembly
2. Change `EFContext` to inherit `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` (Identity assemblies will be added to this assembly also)
3. Add mappings for Identity tables, you can find them here: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/IdentityDbContext.cs

The key to this approach is to understand that IdentityDbContext is just a DbContext with some default mappings.